# If I want to inspect a table row with xpath

Tags: php, search, xpath

AS part of a cURL operation I have some parsing I need to do. The data I want resides at `../table/tr/td`, with said `td` being multiple cells containg many strings, one of which is `<b>34 PT</b>`, however the number is random and I cannot figure out how to just simply do a 'wildcard' or similar.

The suggestions I've found:

```
/tr[contains(@td, 'PT')]" );
```

does not return any results, nor does:

```
/tr/td[contains( @b, 'PT' ) ]
```

I've removed any kind of search at the end and it returns all of the cells as expected, so I know the data is there. The table cells that contain PT have an `<a href>` that I need to know.

Here is an example of the entire html:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<tr>
<td width="120" valign="top" align="center">
<a href="submit.phtml?PT_id=86343434&xcn=b22c57866bfc2bac89b09527b05b7760&location_id=0">
<img height="80" width="80" border="1" alt="" src=".gif">
</a>
<b>3423 PT</b>
<td>
<td>
<tr>
<td> ...and so on
```

The xpath query was used like this:

```
@$dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML( $rawPage );
    @$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    @$queryResult = $xpath->query( " //html/body/div[3]/div[3]/table/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tr/td/div/div/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]" );
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the `@` is used to select attributes not node values... what happens if you do `/tr/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]`

Comment: Paste the code that uses the xpath.  Are you using SimpleXML?

Comment: @Russ it works! You should make it an answer so I can choose it. Removing the @ symbol did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `@` symbol so it inspects the element values and not its attributes

ie `/tr/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]`

Comment: For the record, I added how I called this to the original question